# Problem with One To One Relation EF6 and primary key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have 3 tables

User > Employee > Operator

There is a one to one relation on each other's end

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? LoginDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive{ get; set; }    

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual  Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public class Employee 
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get;set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; } 


    public virtual Operator Operator{ get; set; }  
}

public class Operator
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Employee")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
    public EmployeeEmployee{ get; set; }
}
```

However this does create the one to one relation when i create a diagram in Sql Server MS to check the relations.

Problem is, when I'm just trying to insert data directly graphically from Sql it expects me to insert the primary key on Employee and Operator tables. Why aren't they automatic like the User one?

Comment: Why do the `Id` properties have the `ForeignKey` attributes?

Comment: Because this is what was in the tutorial how to configure one to one relation https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need specify two variables to store same informations.

```
public int UserId { get;set; }
public int EmployeeId {get;set;}
```

already stored in Id. Not need to duplicate it.

Foreign keys doesn't use identity (doesn't generate values). So you need create User and then create an Employe where set the "User" property with user created before. (Main idea is that you need initialise reference to foreign key manually)

```
User user = new User{...};
Employee employe = new Employee{User = user, ...};
context.Add(employee);
context.SaveChanges();
```

**Or maybe you will use hierarchy.** (I don`t checked on 3 level, but on 2 this works perfectly).

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; } 
    public DateTime? LoginDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive{ get; set; }    

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : User
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class Operator : Employee
{

}
```